# How to return TRUE or FALSE based on condition of 3 observations for every row?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, conditional-statements

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| ID | antigen | concentration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | a1 | 0.291259335 |
| C001 | a2 | 0.580050639 |
| C001 | a3 | 0.002235505 |
| C001 | a4 | 0.848792002 |
| C002 | a1 | 0.066808174 |
| C002 | a2 | 0.130661773 |
| C002 | a3 | 0.000530089 |
| C002 | a4 | 0.194151877 |
| C003 | a1 | 0.0142237 |
| C003 | a2 | 0.027409926 |
| C003 | a3 | 0.000117995 |
| C003 | a4 | 0.042202259 |

Each participant has 4 antigens associated with it, and the mean concentration for each antigen has to fall within a specific range, which is different for each antigen.

I'm trying to create a function where each participant-antigen-concentration combination is checked and a TRUE/FALSE is returned in a new column. For example if Participant = C001, antigen = a1, and Concentration is between 0.77 and 1.43, return TRUE. If for any combination of participant and antigen the concentration is out of range, return FALSE.

I've tried using for loops, if else functions and other inefficient ways but have come up short. I don't think I'm approaching this in as logical way as I should so if anyone could point me in the direction of any useful functions or documentation for this kind of problem I'd be very grateful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Try `with(df1, concentration >= 0.77 & 0.77 <= 1.43)`, where df1 is your data.frame.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `case_when`:

```r
df <- tibble(ID = c("C001", "C001", "C002", "C002"),
             antigen = c("a1", "a2", "a1", "a2"),
             concentration = c(0.291259335, 0.580050639, 0.066808174, 0.130661773))
      
library(tidyverse)
       
df |>
  mutate(within_range = case_when(antigen == "a1" & between(concentration, 0.77, 1.43) ~ TRUE,
                                  antigen == "a2" & between(concentration, 0.1, 0.5) ~ TRUE,
                                  TRUE ~ FALSE)
         )
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  ID    antigen concentration within_range
  <chr> <chr>           <dbl> <lgl>       
1 C001  a1             0.291  FALSE       
2 C001  a2             0.580  FALSE       
3 C002  a1             0.0668 FALSE       
4 C002  a2             0.131  TRUE
```